# How to store and access voxel sphere in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, 3d, volume, voxel

I generate a voxel sphere (ellipsoid) in the code below.

```cs
        struct Volume {
          private int3 r; // radiuses of ellipsoid (3 integers for 3 axes)

          public IEnumerable<int3> Iterate()
          {
            for (var x = -r.x; x <= r.x; x++)
            for (var y = -r.y; y <= r.y; y++)
            for (var z = -r.z; z <= r.z; z++)
                if (x * x + y * y + z * z <= r.x * r.y * r.z)
                    yield return int3(x, y, z);
          }
          // return number/index of a point generated in the method above
          public int IndexOf(int3 point) => ??? 
        }
```

Then I collect all the entries in a list

```cs
            var sphere = new Volume(3);  // radius of sphere is 3
            var pointsInSphere = sphere.Iterate().ToArray();
```

Is there way to implement the method `IndexOf` without searching the point in the array?
For example, we can easily do that for a cuboid of voxels: `index = point.x*sizeY*sizeZ + point.y*sizeZ + point.z`, but I find it too complicated to do the same for a sphere and don't know if that's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well this also interests me. Way to go is if you can order voxals in some orderly fashion, so you can mathematically describe its position.

For example if you have 2D array represented in array, You will do `int(width*height)` instead of `int(height)(width)`.

Also reverting with :

```
Count = width * height
Width = count % width
Height = count / width
```

So we are essentially looking to make array of arrays that would represent sphere and coordinates needed to be mappable to indexes of those arrays.